# error: passing ‘const Complex’ as ‘this’ argument of '....' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the * operator in C++, in terms of Complex numbers. I also declared a constant I which is inside the class file (Complex.h). The Complex.cpp is the implementation of the class. The main file is for testing. However, it cannot be compiled. How to fix it?

```
error: passing ‘const Complex’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 cout << "Actual:" << (I * I) << endl;
```

This is my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.cpp"  //remove it 
#include "Complex.h"
using namespace std;
int main (){
    // test multiplication
    cout << "\nExpected:I*I = -1" << endl;
    cout << "Actual:" << (I * I) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is  my Header file:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
#include <cstdlib> //exit
#include <iostream>

class Complex{
    public:
    Complex(double a, double b);
    Complex(double a);
    double real() const{ 
        return a;
    }

    double imag() const{
        return b;
    }
    Complex operator*(const Complex& c2);
    private:
    double a;
    double b;
};

//define a constant i
const Complex I(0,1);
#endif
```

This is the implementation file:

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

Complex::Complex(double realNum, double imagNum):a(realNum),b(imagNum){}

Complex::Complex(double realNum):a(realNum),b(0){}

Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex& c2){
    double c = c2.real(), d = c2.imag();
    return Complex((a*c-b*d),(b*c+a*d));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your statement `(I * I)` multiplies two `const Complex`, and such you can only use the `const` methods of the class. However, your `operator*` is available only in a non-const version.

To correct, just declare it as `const` via

```
Complex operator*(const Complex& c2) const;
```

and the same in the implementation.

---

EDIT: More in detail: You basically have two possibilities to declare a binary operator, either outside a class as

```
Complex operator*(Complex const& a, Complex const& b);
```

or inside of it via

```
Complex operator*(Complex const& a) const;
```

You chose the in-class version. So, when the compiler sees `(I*I)`, where both are `const`, it translates the expression into  `I.operator*(I)`. In order to do so, however, `operator*` has to be `const` as as well, otherwise it can't be called from the constant `I`. This is because the compiler must assume the method is going to change `I`, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Why do you say "only const methods can be called."?

Comment: If an object is `const`, you can't call `non-const` member functions. The compiler has to assume that these change your class, so it wouldn't be constant anymore. You can read [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) about const-correctness.

Comment: you are trying to call `operator*(const Complex&, const Complex&)` and your operator is `operator*(Complex&, const Complex&)`(This is just to prove point, it may not actually be like this)

Comment: So you mean, the * function is considered to be a non-accessor without putting const. Therefore, the complier thought I want to mutate the constant I?

Comment: if member function is not marked as const, it is allowed to modify state of any member variable, and can only be passed nonconstant variable of that type into it. This is exactly your case, because you try to call the `operator*` on const Complex&, but you only provide `operator*` for nonconst instance

Comment: you have a typo, it should've been `I.operator*(I)` not `operator()`

Comment: @Creris: thanks, fixed. That comes from using this bracket thing all the time ;-)